# Basic savegames for a text based game

Tags: python

OK, I know how basic this will seem but I'm not really mastered the basics yet. So, I'm trying to write variables as text into a file, then retrieve them to use when I restart the game.

Comment: [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) may be what you need

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried? `Pickle` is one sugestion, but there are other ways too (regular txt file, xml, etc.)

Comment: @blablatros, I tried using a txt file but it wouldn't let me reassign the text to any variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module is probably what you're looking for. Note that `shelve` uses  [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) internally, so it will be able to handle any Python object.

Here's how it works. First, you open the shelve:

```
import shelve

data = shelve.open("savegame")
```

The, you play around with the data:

```
data["foo"] = "bar"
```

Then, when you're done, you sync the `shelve` to the filesystem:

```
data.sync()
```

Then, when you re-open the `shelve`, `data["foo"]` will still be set to `"bar"`.